# How to get env variables from env in github action .yaml in Vite project

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, github-actions, vite

I want to set an **environment variable** in **github action** `.yaml`. And I can access that variable inside my Vite project run time.
Exp:

```yaml
# staging.yaml - my github action file
...
env: VITE_INTERNAL = true
...
```

```js
// index.vue - my Vite project
function myTest(){
    console.log(process.env.VITE_INTERNAL) // I hope to get "true" instead of "undefined"
}
```

Anyone can help me, please. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

To set an environment variable in a GitHub Action YAML, you can use [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env), [`jobs.<job_id>.env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv), or [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv):

```yaml
name: Build

permissions:
  contents: read
  issues: read
  checks: write
  pull-requests: write

on: push

#  global env
env:
  VITE_INTERNAL: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    #  or job-level env
    env:
      VITE_INTERNAL: true

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 18.x
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm i
    - name: Build
      run: npm run build

      #  or step-level env
      env:
        VITE_INTERNAL: true
```

To access the environment variable from JavaScript, use `import.meta.env.VITE_INTERNAL` (not `process.env.VITE_INTERNAL`).

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vite-github-action-env)

Comment: Thank you for your demo app. But in my case, I have a Dockerfile that my project is built in docker (instead of build ourside and dockerfile just have copy `/dist`. I wander whether building project inside docker makes my app can not get env var. Because I also used `import.meta.env.VITE_INTERNAL` but it was still `undefined`

Comment: Can you show your action yaml that defines the env var? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the docs [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html), but to expose env variables, you can do it like the following.

**.env**

```
VITE_INTERNAL = true
```

**.yaml**

```
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_INTERNAL)
```

Comment: I don't want to have .env files, because I will have several environmental variables along with severals  NODE_ENV. So I want to get env var from only one place :/